# fixing precision of static_cast<int>() in c++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    cin >> a;
    int b = (int) a*100;
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

If you input 2.53, it gives b=252

I know it's a precision thing, but how do you fix it without using comparison?

Answer (score 5):

If a is guaranteed to be positive, use:

```
int b = (int) (a*100+0.5);
```

If not use:

```
int b = (int) floor(a*100+0.5);
```

Float to int cast truncates (rounds towards zero).

If you want to keep truncating, but only want to avoid precision issues, use a small epsilon (1e-4) instead of 0.5 int the code above.

Comment: seems to be the only way doing it. I used to program in java so this issue looks perfectly weird to me.

Comment: @user990808: That issue is exactly the same in Java, if you want just test it. Conversions from floating point to integer types discard the non-integer part, no matter how close to the next integer the value actually is.

Answer (score 2):

You want to round instead of truncating.  The floor function is handy for this:

```
int b = (int)floor(a*100+0.5);
```